# I installed Breeze theme on magento 2.3.2

Tags: magento2

I installed "Breeze blank" theme on magento 2.3.2 through composer but I can't find it under magento/app/design/frontend/(theme) or /magento/app/code

The theme is installed and is being used but not sure on how to edit it?

Comment: Confirm theme install properly without any error on composer command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you installed the module via composer then you should be able to find the theme files in the vendor directory.

Keep in mind that you don't want to make changes to files in the vendor directory, as you will lose your changes next time you update the module.

You will likely want to implement any modifications via overrides, custom modules, etc.